# Google Maps api v2 not working and closes unexpectedly

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

Im almost just a beginner in android. I was trying to make a very simple app with google maps, ie just displaying maps. I followed the following link:

```
file:///C:/Android/Android%20Google%20Maps%20V2%20Tutorial.htm
```

But when I test it on my device it says it has stopped working and closes.

Here is my Manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.googleapi"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission       android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<!-- Required to show current location -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.googleapi.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
 android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
 android:value="AIzaSyA5BsIL-3rppsOxQOuX4gBZT3c0cTHNbWc" />

</application>

</manifest>
```

Acyivity code is: (I tried extending FragementActivity but dosent work with it too.)

```
 package com.example.googleapi;

 import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;

 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
  import android.view.Menu;
  import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

// Google Map
private GoogleMap googleMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    try {
        // Loading map
        initilizeMap();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

/**
 * function to load map. If map is not created it will create it for you
 * */
private void initilizeMap() {
    if (googleMap == null) {
        googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.map)).getMap();

        // check if map is created successfully or not
        if (googleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    initilizeMap();
}

}
```

and XML code is( some part of it):

```
    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

My logcat is:

```
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
        at com.example.googleapi.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)

        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml 
        does not have the right value.  Expected 4030500 but found 0.  
        You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.n(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.v(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.u(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.cE(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
        at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4785)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
        ... 21 more
```

I have googled a lot about it and got some direct questions on it but no answer ?? .

It seems many have the same problem.Can anyone help with this problem. I want to develop an app but not able to proceed as Google mpas api is main part of it.

Comment: i have edited my post to include my logcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are missing a meta tag in the application tag of manifest

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

You should use `SupportMapFragment` instead of `MapFragment`.

Change

```
<fragment
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

to

```
<fragment
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Change

```
 googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
            R.id.map)).getMap();
```

TO

```
googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
            R.id.map)).getMap();
```

Comment: thanks a lot man.... it worked for me like after 3 - 4 days of struggle... As im still a noob can u tell me what next should i learn in google maps api ?? It will be really kind of u...Thanks again :)

Comment: @user2696258 Follow the docs. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2

Comment: oh sorry i thought we can select multiple answers at a time, i selected yours only.. I have followed the docs can u tell the next step or app i should do to get more about maps.. just now i have a mapview but i cannot navigate.

Comment: @user2696258 you have a new problem ask a new question

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you have done is ok with older version of GooglePlayServices, but its apparently visible from your logcat that you are using GooglePlayServices 13 or higher so you need to add the meta data tag in your manifest just the way Raghunandan have answered.

Comment: this is a comment rather than an answer